# Python logging file is updated, but nothing is printed to stdout although level is set

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I'm trying to use a basic python (v2.7.5) logger:

```
import logging

TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
LOG_PATH = "/tmp/exaple.log"

logging.basicConfig(
    format=LOG_FORMAT,
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename=LOG_PATH,
    datefmt=TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
)

logger = logging.getLogger("exaple")

logger.error("example")
```

As you can see, 'level' is set to logging.DEBUG, the line appears at example.log as expected, yet nothing is printed! Why?

Comment: Why would anything be printed?

Comment: When you put it like this :) well, I guess I assumed it'd be streamed to stdout in additon by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set 1 handler, here is multiple handlers example

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters